# Why is Rectangle intersect never true?

Tags: android, sprite, intersect

I have the following function, which shall tell me when 2 sprites overlap on the x-axis:

```
public int getSecondObjectX(int secObjWidth)
    {
        int rndX = random.nextInt(AndroidApplication.getInstance().device_width - secObjWidth);

        Rect sObj = new Rect(rndX, 20, rndX + secObjWidth, 10);
        Rect droid = new Rect(myAnimation.getXcord(), 20, myAnimation.getXcord() + myAnimation.getCurrentImage().getWidth(), 10);

        Log.d("Compare Rect", "["+sObj.left+", "+sObj.right+"] ["+droid.left+", "+droid.right+"]");

        if(Rect.intersects(sObj, droid))
        {
            Log.d("INTERSECT", "INTERSECT");

            return getSecondObjectX(secObjWidth);
        }
        else
            return rndX;
    }
```

But I never get the intersect, here's the Logcat:

```
03-19 15:08:12.617: D/Compare Rect(631): [183, 231] [141, 189] <-- should be true
03-19 15:08:22.186: D/Compare Rect(631): [158, 206] [172, 220] <-- should be true
03-19 15:08:26.346: D/Compare Rect(631): [123, 171] [178, 226]
03-19 15:08:30.146: D/Compare Rect(631): [156, 204] [155, 203] <-- should be supertrue
03-19 15:08:32.617: D/Compare Rect(631): [84, 132] [172, 220]
```

What's the problem?

Comment: read the * manual, you're using Rect wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you construct the `Rect`s is wrong. The [`public Rect (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor does not perform range checking. You can find the following in the documentation:

> Note: no range checking is performed, so the caller must ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom.

In your case, top > bottom.